# What are the steps to use Anonymous Identity based Token Vending Machine with AWS CloudFront?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I find no documentation and material to use use Anonymous Identity based Token Vending Machine with AWS CloudFront. Can someone explain the steps please? Many thanks.